# Find files NOT containing text in command prompt including a certain file type but excluding files that contain certain text in their file names

Tags: windows, command-line, find

I want to find files in a specific directory NOT containing certain text (case insensitive). I also want to include a certain path but exclude another path. How can I accomplish this?

This is what I have so far...but I'm not sure what to do with the "not in exclude" portion below, as this does not work:

```
@for /r %f in (*.vbhtml) not in (*exclude.vbhtml) do @find "invalid" "%f" > nul || echo %f
```

Comment: That not possible with `for /r` and `@find` requires `forfiles` (which also doesn't have an exclude option).

Comment: Consider using powershell. `Get-ChildItem` has an `-exclude string` option.